# How to reset search item on Master Detail page?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have link which navigate to Master Detail page and perform search, it works well.
But, when I change page and back again to MD (through navigation) search item still hold the value from link.

How can I clear search item when I change page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear its value in Pre-rendering process.